# Django / Python - sorting different Class objects sharing the same attribute?

Tags: python, django, sorting

So let's say I have the following models in Django:

```
class Review(models.Model): 
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(("Date"), default=timezone.now)

class Rating(models.Model): 
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(("Date"), default=timezone.now)
```

And my view looks like this:

```
def get_page(request, id_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(attribute=id_slug).order_by('-datetime')
    ratings = Rating.objects.filter(attribute=id_slug).order_by('-datetime')
    context_dict['reviews'] = reviews
    context_dict['ratings'] = ratings
return render(request, 'page.html', context_dict)
```

What I want to do is make a query set that would include both Review and Rating objects, ordered by the datetime attribute, so something like:

```
activity =  reviewsANDratings.order_by('-datetime')
context_dict['activity'] = activity
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your models are basically the same thing, or parent/child of one another, consider using [Django polymorphic](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic), which will let you get all the `Review`s *and* `Rating`s in one `PolymorphicQuerySet`.

For more disparate models, (or for simpler implementation), just do two queries, like you are now, and merge the items in Python like so:

```
reviews_and_ratings = sum([list(reviews), list(ratings)], [])
reviews_and_ratings.sort(key=lambda item: item.datetime, reverse=True)
context_dict['reviews_and_ratings'] = reviews_and_ratings
```

Comment: Thank you! 

I chose to go with the second option since my models also contain more different attributes. It worked, the only thing I had to change was to convert the query sets to lists first as it would not let me concatenate query sets. :) 

(I upvoted you but it does not show up on the page since I'm a new user)

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer, no matter how new you are.  As for conversion to lists, I forgot about this and thought the second argument to `sum()` would suffice - I'll edit the answer now.